# Centos 7 Apache Php 7.4 string(1040384) limit when file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: php, ionic3, centos7, php-7.4, cakephp-2.x

I need help to get the POST JSON request from `file_get_contents('php://input')`, I am posting file and data from Ionic 3 Angular but every time I submit, I got `string(1040384)` limit when `var_dump` out the result. The string looks like chop half way and not complete. I have tried using 8MB file, 900kb file and all not work. The only works is below 600kb which is `string(900000)+`. I have updated the PHP ini `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to 55MB and 50MB. My php version is 7.4.

I have print_r and strlen and still get the same value, even save into database also the same

Is there configuration that I missed out?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure you updated the correct php.ini file? There is usually one for command line and a separate one for Apache, for example. Also, did you restart Apache after making that change?

Comment: yes, I add in CPANEL, normally this not required restart apache because the config is saved in .htaccess

Comment: Create a PHP page that has just `<?php phpinfo();` in it, and load that in your browser to check what the active settings are. That will tell you whether your changes are having any effect.